# qsub Job using GNU parallel not running

Tags: qsub

I am trying execute qsub job in a multinode(2) and PPN of 20 using GNU parallel, However it shows some error.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=20
#PBS -l walltime=02:00:00
#PBS -N down

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
module load gnu-parallel

for cdr in /scratch/data/v/mt/Downscale/*;do
  (cp /scratch/data/v/mt/DWN_FILE_NEW/* $cdr/)
  (cd $cdr && parallel -j20 --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE 'echo {} | ./vari_1st_imge' ::: *.DS0 )
done
```

When I run the above code I got the following error(Please note all the path are properly checked, and the same code without qsub is running properly in a normal computer)

```
$ ./down 
parallel: Error: Cannot open echo {} | ./vari_1st_imge.
```

& for $qsub down -- no output is creating

I am using parallel --version
GNU parallel 20140622

Please help to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try adding `--dryrun` to `parallel`.

But my feeling is that `$PBS_NODEFILE` is not set for some reason, and that GNU Parallel tries to read the command as the `--sshloginfile`.

To test this:

```
echo $PBS_NODEFILE
(cd $cdr && parallel --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE -j20 'echo {} | ./vari_1st_imge' ::: *.DS0 )
```

If GNU Parallel now tries to open `-j20` then it is clear that it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried without --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE the code runs. Could you suggest me how to set $PBS_NODEFILE. Now the error shows when I try using the above : ./down: line 14: module: command not found

parallel: Error: Cannot open echo {} | ./vari_1st_imge.

Comment: The script cannot locate the `parallel` binary. Verify if and where it resides on the nodes (e.g., run an interactive job and search for it, or just ask the cluster admin), and then put the full path to the binary, or add the path to the `PATH` environment variable at the beginning of the script. . The system may also already be set up to include it with the `module` command.

Comment: Your PBS admin will know why $PBS_NODEFILE is not set. I have never used PBS systems myself, but it is my impression that PBS normally sets this variable by itself.